# Peculiar behavior of ArrayList remove() - Why?

Tags: java, arraylist

When we remove `-1` from and empty `ArrayList` it throws `ConcurrentModificationException` and when we remove `0` from same empty `ArrayList` it throws `NoSuchElementException`.

Please find the code below :

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
        try {
            list.remove(-1);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        }
        try {
            it.next();// Throwing ConcurrentModificationException
        } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
            System.err.println("ConcurrentModificationException 1");
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.err.println("NoSuchElementException 1 ");
        }

        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        it = list.iterator();
        try {
            list.remove(0);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
        try {
            it.next();// Throwing NoSuchElementException
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.err.println("NoSuchElementException 2");
        } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
            System.err.println("ConcurrentModificationException 2 ");
        }

    }
}
```

From my understanding `NoSuchElementException` is fine but why `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown ?

Comment: That is now iterators work, if you modify the list, you call `list.remove`, then the iterator will throw a CME. The difference between the calls I suspect has to do with what happens with `list.remove(0)` vs `list.remove(-1)`

Answer (score 4):

If you check the code for ArrayList. First a range check is performed, then a modification count is added.

```
rangeCheck(index);
modCount++;
```

In the range check method, the range check is for positive numbers only.

```
if (index >= size)
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
```

So `remove(0)` doesn't add a mod count, but `remove(-1)` does. The modCount causes the iterator to throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: But why is it implemented this way?

Comment: @MiljenMikic in [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.rangeCheck%28int%29) for version 8u40 b25 it is still just a positive range check for the remove(int).

Comment: @algrid what implementation are you referring to? The fact the iterator throws a concurrent modification exception, or the fact the range check is only for positive integers?

Comment: @matt the fact that the check is for positive numbers only

Comment: @algrid They *have* to check for positive numbers because the backing array is larger than the size. For negative numbers, the array itself will throw the exception. So it would essentially be double checking for negative numbers.

Comment: @matt yes, but as a result the code gives `ConcurrentModificationException` where no modification happened. It looks like sacrificing correctness for the sake of speed or compatibility.

Comment: @algrid In some ways, I feel a CME should be thrown in both cases. I find it odd that the mod count isn't incremented before the range check. Even though the operation failed, something is attempting to modify the list while an iterator is in use.

Answer (score 3):

It is (IMO) a bug, albeit a very minor one.

The code looks like this (in Java 8):

```
 public E remove(int index) {
     rangeCheck(index);
     modCount++;
     E oldValue = elementData(index);
```

The `rangeCheck` call checks that `index < size`, but not `index >= 0`.  Presumably, that is to avoid a redundant check ... because the `elementData` call does a non-optimizable array bounds check that deals with the negative index case.

But the catch is that the `modCount++` is happening before the array bounds check.  Ooops!

A potential fix would be to move the `modCount++` after the `elementData` call, but this may not be correct.  The deal is that `modCount` is a `volatile`, and therefore reading / writing it has an implicit synchronizing effect for the access to the `elementData` that happens next.

Would they fix it if you reported it?  Probably not!

- Fixing it has the potential to break code that "works" if you do it the way I suggested above.  Admittedly the code that you are breaking is incorrect anyway because it is relying on the serendipitous synchronization due to the `volatile`.  Even so, people whose code broke would **scream**.  (Not least because this would be a difficult breakage to diagnose.)
- Alternatively, if you add an explicit `size >= 0` check, you most likely make working code *measurably* slower.
- The "bug" only affects code that is incorrect anyway.  You should not be calling `ArrayList::remove` concurrently with an iteration.